# Android - is this the correct way to send a single UDP packet?

Tags: android, user-interface, networking, crash, packet

I'm trying to send a UDP packet in Android with a button press. This is what I did until now:

```
 public void sendUdp(View view)
{
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                HelloText.setText("tfi");
                DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
                InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.0.4");
                byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
                sendData = "Hello".getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 15000);
                sendPacket.setLength(sendData.length);
                clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

This is the XML of the button that is pressed on to send the packet:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/sender"
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/secondact"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:onClick="sendUdp"/>
```

I've also added this to the Android Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

When I try to send, this error pops up in the log (using Android Studio and running with my Galaxy S4, Android 5.0 connected with USB):

```
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
```

The packet is not being sent - a server that works perfectly fine doesn't receive it at all.

Does it mean I'm sending incorrectly? What's the problem here?

Comment: That is not an error. `D/` is a debug message.

Comment: The packet isn't sending though. It is not being received on the end it should (the server works, I checked, it's just the packet not sending).

Comment: Rather than ignoring exceptions, log them (`Log.e("yo", "done blow'd up", e);` in your `catch` block). **Never** have a `catch` block that does nothing.

Comment: It doesn't even throw an exception, though. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

am I correct in guessing `HelloText` is a `TextView` or (EditView etc)?  if so this is the cause of your problem ...

You can't call methods (eg `setText`) on a widget (eg `TextView`) from any thread other than the main/ui thread